# XML to parse eCFR - again

Tags: xslt, filemaker

Once more into the breach. 
I am looking to derive ordered pairs of information from an XML source for use in a lookup table in a database. The XML is very flat as its structure relates instructions for typesetting the documents. Data is not differentiated except by its format in this XML. A sample of the XML is as follows:

```
    <APPENDIX>
              <EAR>Pt. 774, Supp. 1</EAR>
              <HD SOURCE="HED">Supplement No. 1 to Part 774—The Commerce Control List</HD>
              <HD SOURCE="HD1">Category 0—Nuclear Materials, Facilities, and Equipment [and Miscellaneous Items]</HD>
              <HD SOURCE="HD1">A. “End Items,” “Equipment,” “Accessories,” “Attachments,” “Parts,” “Components,” and “Systems”</HD>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-2">
                <E T="02">0A002Power generating or propulsion equipment “specially designed” for use with space, marine or mobile “nuclear reactors”. (These items are “subject to the ITAR.” See 22 CFR parts 120 through 130.)</E>
              </FP>

              <FP SOURCE="FP-2">
                <E T="02">0A018Items on the Wassenaar Munitions List (see List of Items Controlled).</E>
              </FP>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-1">
                <E T="04">License Requirements</E>
              </FP>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-1">
                <E T="03">Reason for Control:</E> NS, AT, UN</FP>
              <GPOTABLE CDEF="s50,r50" COLS="2" OPTS="L2">
                <BOXHD>
                  <CHED H="1">Control(s)</CHED>
                  <CHED H="1">Country Chart (See Supp. No. 1 to part 738)</CHED>
                </BOXHD>
                <ROW>
                  <ENT I="01">NS applies to entire entry</ENT>
                  <ENT>NS Column 1.</ENT>
                </ROW>
                <ROW>
                  <ENT I="01">AT applies to entire entry</ENT>
                  <ENT>AT Column 1.</ENT>
                </ROW>
                <ROW>
                  <ENT I="01">UN applies to entire entry</ENT>
                  <ENT>See § 746.1(b) for UN controls.</ENT>
                </ROW>
              </GPOTABLE>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-1">
                <E T="05">List Based License Exceptions (See Part 740 for a description of all license exceptions)</E>
              </FP>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-1">
                <E T="03">LVS:</E> $3,000 for 0A018.b</FP>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-1">$1,500 for 0A018.c and .d</FP>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-1">
                <E T="03">GBS:</E> N/A</FP>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-1">
                <E T="03">CIV:</E> N/A</FP>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-1">
                <E T="04">List of Items Controlled</E>
              </FP>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-1">
                <E T="03">Related Controls:</E> (1) See also 0A979, 0A988, and 22 CFR 121.1 Categories I(a), III(b-d), and X(a). (2) See ECCN 0A617.y.1 and .y.2 for items formerly controlled by ECCN 0A018.a. (3) See ECCN 1A613.c for military helmets providing less than NIJ Type IV protection and ECCN 1A613.y.1 for conventional military steel helmets that, immediately prior to July 1, 2014, were classified under 0A018.d and 0A988. (4) See 22 CFR 121.1 Category X(a)(5) and (a)(6) for controls on other military helmets.</FP>
              <FP SOURCE="FP-1">
                <E T="03">Related Definitions:</E> N/A</FP>
              <FP>
                <E T="03">Items:</E> a. [Reserved]</FP>
              <P>b. “Specially designed” components and parts for ammunition, except cartridge cases, powder bags, bullets, jackets, cores, shells, projectiles, boosters, fuses and components, primers, and other detonating devices and ammunition belting and linking machines (all of which are “subject to the ITAR.” (See 22 CFR parts 120 through 130);</P>
              <NOTE>
                <HD SOURCE="HED">
                  <E T="03">Note:</E>
                </HD>
                <P>
                  <E T="03">0A018.b does not apply to “components” “specially designed” for blank or dummy ammunition as follows:</E>
                </P>
                <P>
                  <E T="03">a. Ammunition crimped without a projectile (blank star);</E>
                </P>
 </APPENDIX>
```

Also attached are two XSL samples. The first will obtain the ECCN numbers from the nodes FP/E where the attributes are "FP-2" and "02", respectively. The second uses an xsl:if statement to obtain the "Reasons for Control" also from node FP. In this latter case the IF statement is used to determine whether the E node within the FP node includes the "Reason/s for Control" text.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//FP[@SOURCE = 'FP-2']/E[@T='02']">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>\n
    </xsl:for-each>          
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//FP[@SOURCE = 'FP-1']">
        <xsl:if test= "E='Reason for Control:' or E='Reasons for Control:'">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>\n
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output that I need is an ordered pair of the preceding ECCN and Reasons for Control information. My thought would be that if one were to move down the list to each FP node and perform a test on its attributes, keeping the correct ones as suggested above by the XSL samples, I should get a 1D list of the necessary information with an ECCN followed by its matching Reasons for Control, if any. However, I get most of the text of the original XML with a whole lot of "Nothing" thrown in. In other words, I am apparently matching the FP nodes, but the 'when' statements are not being satisfied for some reason.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FP">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@Source='FP-2'">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>\n
            </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@Source='FP-1'">
            <xsl:if test= "E='Reason for Control:' or E='Reasons for Control:'">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>\n
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            Nothing
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I believe that if I can obtain a 1D list as described above, that I would be able to later get this into a Filemaker database. Given these premises, can anyone offer any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: "*The output that I need is an ordered pair of the preceding ECCN and Reasons for Control information.*" Please post the exact output you expect to get as a result of transforming the input example **as code**. -- "*get this into a Filemaker database*" As I [already advised on your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887091/xpath-to-parse-ecfr-xml-using-attributes-and-nodes#comment51741507_31888462), formulate your request in terms of records and fields. IOW, post the expected result in FMPXMLRESULT grammar.

Comment: Michael - I feel that there is only so much hand holding I can, in good conscience, request from you all. In any case, I'm confident that I'll be able to handle a 1D list having the form: 
ECCN
Reasons for Control
ECCN
Reasons for Control
ECCN
Reasons for Control
ECCN 
Reasons for Control Reasons for Control
 Output in pure text or in XML having this form will be sufficient.

Comment: I am afraid you're misinterpreting my request. I am asking you to make it **easier** for us to help you, by providing an **exact** requirement. Having to deal with a vague description is much more time-consuming.

Comment: Fair enough. Hope this is viewable. /n <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
  <METADATA>
    <FIELD NAME="ECCNFP_2" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD NAME="ECCNFP_1" TYPE="TEXT"/>
  </METADATA>
  <RESULTSET>

    <ROW>
      <COL><DATA>0A002</DATA></COL>
      <COL><DATA></DATA></COL>      
    </ROW>

    <ROW>
      <COL><DATA>0A018</DATA></COL>
      <COL><DATA>NS, AT, UN</DATA></COL>      
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <COL><DATA>0A521</DATA></COL>
      <COL><DATA>NS, RS, AT, UN</DATA></COL>      
    </ROW>
  </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>

Comment: No, please don't post code in comments. Add this to your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think I understand from this very confusing description:

1. There are two types of nodes of interest here; the first one can be selected
   by:

   ```
   /APPENDIX/FP[@SOURCE='FP-2'][E[@T='02']]
   ```

   and the second one by:

   ```
   /APPENDIX/FP[@SOURCE='FP-1'][E[@T='03']='Reason for Control:']
   ```

   These nodes are siblings.
2. The nodes of the second type are related to the first
   preceding-sibling node of the first type; Not every node of the first
   type has a related node of the second type.

Based on these assumptions, the following styleheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k" match="FP[@SOURCE='FP-1'][E[@T='03']='Reason for Control:']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::FP[@SOURCE='FP-2'][E[@T='02']][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/APPENDIX">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
    <METADATA>
        <FIELD NAME="ECCNFP_2" TYPE="TEXT"/> 
        <FIELD NAME="ECCNFP_1" TYPE="TEXT"/> 
    </METADATA>
        <RESULTSET> 
            <xsl:for-each select="FP[@SOURCE='FP-2'][E[@T='02']]">
                <ROW>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="substring(E[@T='02'], 1, 5)"/></DATA></COL> 
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="key('k', generate-id())/text()"/></DATA></COL> 
                </ROW> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RESULTSET> 
    </FMPXMLRESULT> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input example (after correcting the unclosed `<NOTE>` element!), will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
   <METADATA>
      <FIELD NAME="ECCNFP_2" TYPE="TEXT"/>
      <FIELD NAME="ECCNFP_1" TYPE="TEXT"/>
   </METADATA>
   <RESULTSET>
      <ROW>
         <COL>
            <DATA>0A002</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA/>
         </COL>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
         <COL>
            <DATA>0A018</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA> NS, AT, UN</DATA>
         </COL>
      </ROW>
   </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

Comment: Michael - Thank you for the assistance. To ensure that I understand the solution, you have assigned a unique key to each 'reason for control' that is the first preceding-sibling of the matched node. Thereafter you have read in the ECCN and then the reason for control using the matching key. I note from the generated XML that where a 'reason for control' does not exist for a given ECCN, the opening data tag is not inserted into the XML. This does not matter for Filemaker, but I wonder how this is handled for other applications?

Comment: Actually, XSLT assigns a unique ID to every node in the source XML. What the key declaration does is assign a key value to each 'reason for control' that is equal to the ID of the closest preceding ECCN. This allows each ECCN to "find" the corresponding 'reason for control' by calling out its own ID.  Without this, it would be difficult, because from the context of an ECCN the first following 'reason for control' may come after another ECCN. -- I didn't understand the part about "other applications".  Other applications have other XML schemas, so really there's no general answer possible.